# Memory Management

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory

I have resolved memory leaks from my app but my app was still crashing with Program received signal 0. i have checked my app in developer tools. it is showing 30 mb when app launches. It is taking too much memory. how'll i resolve this? anyone has any solution?

Thanks
rajni

Comment: Are you doing something that consumes loads of memory? Loading several large images, text files, massive database?

Comment: iPhone imposes a timeout for application launch, but no real memory limitation. Could it be that your application is taking too much time to startup because struggling for memory?

Comment: no, i m not loading images, textfiles or massive database.

Comment: Noe, As application is not taking much time to startup as there is no database or web service being called the appdelegate just call the viewController

Answer (score 0):

There's not an absolute amount of memory that's okay. If iOS thinks you're using too much it will send you a notification (and there are delegate methods in `UIApplicationDelegate` and `UIViewController` too).

At that point you should release as much memory as you can. If there's nothing to release you'll just have to optimise your app to make it use less space.

You don't say which device you're running on, but in my experience, 30Mb sounds like a lot for the original iPhone and 3G.

Comment: Thanks for replaying me.i am working for ipad..and working with 200MB pdf books in my absolute path.